# MatlabFunction for previous Matlab versions

Tags: matlab, compatibility, handle

I have made a program that runs over symbolic inputs and transform these functions through MatlabFunction command.

However, when running it in older versions, since it was not implemented, it will show an error.

How could I make MatlabFunction compatible with older versions of Matlab?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't. There's no good reason to run MATLAB versions that old.

Comment: So, are there any alternatives for this function for old versions?